# Not able to install sonarlint plugin in Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, sonarlint

Trying to install sonar lint plugin in STS tool, it is not installing and says Sonar lint not compatible with this version of eclipse.

Find the versions details.

```
Spring Tool Suite
Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201511261048
Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)
```

Comment: Can I trouble you for some more details? Where are you getting sonar lint from, what version are you trying to install? are there any more error details, i.e. what exactly is STS/Eclipse complaining about? what method are you using to install (offline, p2 url, marketplace, other?). Thanks for the extra details.

Comment: Sonar lint version is 1.2.0, Trying to drang and drop the plugin from [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint) into my STS and it says not compatible with this version of eclipse.

STS Version -  3.7.2.RELEASE.

Hope you got the details

Answer (score 21):

Hi you can download sonar lint from the follwing URL  http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/ then follow the steps given below

1. Make sure the download location, Don't unpack the archive file(for windows)
2. Go to **install new software** option in eclipse **Help >>** 
   [image]
3. Click **Add** button in right of **work with** text field, following screen will appear
   [image]
4. Fill name location as "Sonar" etc
5. Now select the downloaded archive file by clicking **Archive** button
6. Follow the installation instructions from the Installation window

Answer (score 15):

you can also install zip file of `SonarLint` as follow:

1.go to the site https://bintray.com/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/2.6.0.

2.download the setup jar file and go to help menu of eclipse

[image]

3.click on "install new software"

[image]

4.click on add.

5.click on "archive".

6."open" the jar file from the location you have downloaded the jar.

[image]

7. install the software.

Comment: I am using Oxygen.1a so I installed successfully the https://bintray.com/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/3.5.0

Comment: Here you say "jar", but the file selection is a zip file extension, correct?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what the problem exactly is, but I worked around this by starting up STS, select "Install New Software" and pasted the Solarlint update site URL into that dialog: http://eclipse.sonarlint.org/

That allowed me to install the plugin into STS 3.7.2 without any issues.
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore.  http://eclipse.sonarlint.org/ does not look like an update site. Downloading the package and installing manually from the archive worked for me on STS 3.8.1.

Comment: @wwerner , after downloading may i know where to copy these sonarlint files

Answer (score 1):

Please Make visit to this [link](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint#group-external-install-button) and as i see you are using mars.

**1.** If you have eclipse marketplace installed then you can proceed as per.

[image]

you just need to drag this icon to your eclipse and done.

**2.** If not Installed then also [same link](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/) click on download button and after downloading go to eclipse on right side there is search functionality type `install new software` and then select that option window will pop up choose>>**add** button>>**archive** button>>and **upload zip file** from download location >>**accept agreement** and done click on next done.

If you found it easy and helpful please up-vote happy coding and reviewing with `sonarlint`

Answer (score 1):

1.Download it from https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/

2.In Eclipse go to Help->Install New Software->Add

3.Now click on Archive and select downloaded plugin zip and click Ok

4.Select the items and click Next and then accept license agreement and finally it will ask for a restart

Comment: No longer available there