# install sonarlint in eclipse luna 4.4.0. failure

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Trying to install sonarlint in eclipse luna 4.4.0.
Installing from marketplace failing with below error :

Trying to install sonarlint in eclipse luna 4.4.0.

Unable to read repository at https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org/content.xml.
Received fatal alert: protocol_version

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:201)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:239)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

java version is 1.8
os is windows 8 64 bit

Comment: unable to add "install new software as well" with below error :

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD5 MessageDigest not available
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.License.calculateLicenseDigest(License.java:121)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.License.getUUID(License.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.SimpleLicenseM

Comment: I recommend you to ask on the specific Google group. Sonarlint developers are actively monitoring the Google group but seems not StackOverflow
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarlint

Comment: What is the value of your `-vm` argument in **eclipse.ini**? I resolved this problem setting this argument to a _java 8_ runtime.

Answer (score 3):

To install SolarLint in Eclipse Luna, download the SolarLint plugin and install new software from an archive (the file you downloaded). I was able to download from https://sonarsource.bintray.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/. See the similar question [Not able to install sonarlint plugin in Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876327/not-able-to-install-sonarlint-plugin-in-platform-eclipse-mars-1-4-5-1).