# How to show SonarLint in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, eclipse-mars

I installed SonarLint using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876327/not-able-to-install-sonarlint-plugin-in-platform-eclipse-mars-1-4-5-1?answertab=votes#tab-top) on my ECLIPSE MARS 2 - 4.5.0

I couldn't do it with MarketPlace because of this error: `Can not read the repository at https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org/compositeContent.xml.
Received fatal alert: protocol_version`

The installation was successful, I had no erreor but I can't find SonarLint's view in the window's settings
(Window>Setting).

This is a screenshot of the installed plugins:
[image]

The same result in marcketPlace :

[image]

In Settings :

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using a Java runtime < 1.8 for Eclipse ?
Sonarlint requires a Java runtime >= 1.8.x